# Istio - Per client circuit breaker config

Tags: istio

In Istio, we define the circuit breaker configuration for a target service using a destination rule. This configuration is then applied for all the clients calling the target service.

For example, if I set up a destination rule for service A with maxRequests = 100.

```
spec:
  host: serviceA
  trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      http:
        http2MaxRequests: 100
```

If serviceB, serviceC, and serviceD are calling serviceA, then this rule is application for all three.

Is there a way to configure the circuit breaker separately for serviceB, serviceC, and serviceD?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With istio [circuit breaker](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/circuit-breaking/) it is currently (istio `v1.7`) not possible for a single service to configure circuit breaker per other service. This is because circuit breaker works on specific [connection pool](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ConnectionPoolSettings).

Alternatively you could split service A into 3 separate services that would work individually with services B, C and D:

```
Service B > Service A1
Service C > Service A2
Service D > Service A3
```

This approach obviously would require more resources and could introduce other issues.

More useful information about circuit breaker that is not included in istio documentation can be found on envoy [documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/circuit_breaking), as istio uses envoy circuit breaker.